# unable to use pip for installing python packages

Tags: python, perl, pip

I have just installed python 3.4, including pip, on a win64 machine.
When trying to use pip to install a package, I encounter a strange error.
I'm running:

```
pip install packagename
```

and get:

```
 Can't locate pip.pm in @INC...
```

This looks like a perl error to me. I do have perl installed on my machine, but why is windows trying to invoke perl?
Waiting for your advice,
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why windows is doing that. I guess that the module you're trying to install has some perl dependencies. Well anyways, you can use this : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ It is a pretty decent list for windows setups for python modules.

Comment: I'd check the directories in your $PATH for something called "pip.exe" or "pip.bat" that's not the python tool. Google find some results for cygwin installations with this problem, but no one seems to have posted how they've fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so what did it for me was changing the name of the pip file found somewhere on my drive to pip_pm. This convinced windows to just use the python pip command. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have installed [pip perl module](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/pip-1.19/lib/pip.pm), and it added the pip perl tool in your PATH variable (in upper place than pip from python). So, if you don't use that perl module, you can delete it, or call the python pip tool with the complete path

Comment: Alternatively, move the Python scripts directory earlier in your PATH (perhaps to the beginning).